# Creating database snapshots in Oracle 12

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, database-administration

I have a lengthy daily process on an Oracle database that takes place every evening. I would like to:

1. Take a snapshot of the database at a certain point in the middle
   of the daily process without interrupting it for a long time.
2. Query the snapshot to update a data warehouse database.
3. Drop the snapshot after pulling the necessary data.

I found the below link on Oracle website that describes what I need exactly and calls it a copy-on-write snapshot.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/availability/rman-fra-snapshot-322251.html

The problem is I could not find any help on creating such snapshots as all search results for "snaphsots" are related to materialized views which seemingly were called snaphosts in previous releases.

Is it possible to create a point in time version of a database in a short period of time (not backup / restore) in order to use it for data warehousing?

Comment: That article is talking about the snapshots your storage layer can potentially create.  Many if not most SAN layers these days can generate a point in time snapshot and allow you to mount that snapshot on a different server.  That's not an Oracle technology.  Different SAN vendors have very different implementations of storage snapshots

Comment: @Patriot Before you work on a snapshot solution (which is certainly possible, but often times complex), have you looked into using simple flashback queries first?  It wouldn't be as robust as a snapshot, but it's already setup on your database and easy to use.  You can create point-in-time queries like this: `select * from some_table as of timestamp timestamp '2019-09-23 20:00:00';`.  Alternatively, the pluggable database architecture is supposed to enable quick snapshots, if you have the multitenant option licensed.